# Regression on video slices to learn a score

Tags: video, machine-learning, neural-network, conv-neural-network, lstm

I am stuck in a task. I have to predict a score(0-1) which corresponds to importance of a digital video packet. I have the original video, I am extracting slices from it, and labeling it with frame type(I,B,or P), position of slice and the score I got from a Video Quality Metric, and making the dataset. I don't know how to proceed further w.r.t Learning part. I am thinking of 3d-ConvNets(as feature extraction) + LSTM(memory from previous frames) regression after that, but my slices are rectangular(say for an HD video it's 60*1280), and as far as I know ConvNets work better only with square arrays. Any suggestions regarding architecture etc. would be highly appreciated.